# Radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} { (n \sin{\frac{1}{n}})^{n} x^n } $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

We need to calculate the radius of convergence $R$ of:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\left(n \sin{\frac{1}{n}}\right)^{n} x^n }.$$

Here's what I did:

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} { \left| \frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}\right|} = \lim_{n\to\infty} {\left| \frac{(n\sin{\frac{1}{n}})^n} {((n+1) \sin{\frac{1}{n+1}})^{n+1}} \right|}  $$

But I get to a place like this:
$$= \lim_{n\to\infty} { \left|\frac{1}{n\sin{\frac{1}{n}}} \right|} = \left|\frac{1}{\infty \cdot 0}\right|$$

How do I precisely calculate that limit? Is there a better way to find $R$?

Comment: What is $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:
$$n\sin\frac{1}{n}=\dfrac{\sin\frac1n}{\frac1n}$$

Comment: Lupital ? $=1$ ?

Comment: @TheNotMe: Yes the limit is $1$.